# MacOS Swift App Calling AppleScript to send Outlook Email - Formatting issue

Tags: swift, macos, outlook

I have a MacOS app written in Swift that part of sends an Outlook email via an AppleScript. Everything functions as expected except I can't seem to get new lines in the email message. Tried `\n` and `& return` which is AppleScript's way of adding new lines with no luck.

Here's how I am setting up the string to send to AS:

```
let strJIRATicket = "\(jiraID)\n\(jiraKey)\n\(jiraURL)"

let strMsg:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hi \(writerFName)\n\n\(thisRepoName) has had changes made to it:\n\n\(strDiff.string)\n\nA Jira ticket has been created:\n\n\(strJIRATicket)")
```

I had to use an attributed string for some reason to get Outlook to accept the message part of the email, I guess because the body of an email is RTF text?

Here's a sample of what is being displayed in the email, just one long string with spaces where the breaks should be:

```
Hi Steven iosjazzytest has had changes made to it: commit dfb243b4d6810d81118dbe2ed45d6a309cb5148c Author: XXXXXXXXXXX Date: Tue Feb 18 15:49:55 2020 +0000 File Changed: README.md Changes: +Testing: Made change in bitbucket: 02/17/2020 10:49 A Jira ticket has been created: id:1047229 & return & key:DOC-8240 & return & self:https://jira.xxxxxxx-services.com/rest/api/2/issue/1047229
```

What I was expecting:

```
Hi Steven

iosjazzytest has had changes made to it:

commit dfb243b4d6810d81118dbe2ed45d6a309cb5148c
Author: XXXXXXXXXXX
Date: Tue Feb 18 15:49:55 2020 +0000
File Changed: README.md
Changes: +Testing: Made change in bitbucket: 02/17/2020 10:49

A Jira ticket has been created:

id:1047229
key:DOC-8240
self:https://jira.xxxxxx-services.com/rest/api/2/issue/1047229
```

Realize this is a long shot as AS is not overly used but any idea of how to pass the new lines to Outlook?

Comment: check what mime type you're using, also you can try `\r\n`, or use html `<br>` (with proper mime type)

Comment: Thanks, I will and post back. About to start an afternoon of meetings tho.